# Braintree Transaction.search in Meteor Server

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, wait, braintree

How can I wait for the Braintree Transaction.search() function to return all data.
Right now it does not wait and just comes back with undefined return value.
Here is the code 
I tried to use Meteor.asynwrap but that also does not work. 
 `

```
function getTrxns(cid) {
  var future = new Future();
  var trxns = [];
  var i = 0
  var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
                        r =     search.customerId().is(cid)});

  stream.on("data", function(data){
        i = i+1
        trxns.push({
        'id':data.id,
        'amount':data.amount,
        'crtDt': data.createdAt,
        'ccType': data.creditCard.cardType,
        'currency': data.currencyIsoCode,
        'last4': data.creditCard.last4,
        'expdt': data.creditCard.expirationDate
        });
 });
stream.on("end", function(){
    // print the output in console
    console.log('End Stream cnt: '+i);
    return trxns;
});

stream.resume();
}

Meteor.methods({
 findCustTrxns: function() {
        var btId = Meteor.user().custBtId;       
        if (!btId) { return []; };
        console.log('findCustTrxns cusBtId: '+btId);
        var xx =  getTrxns(btId);
                console.log('xx len :'+xx.length);
 } 

});


OUTPUT is:

I20170509-15:22:09.095(0)?      findCustTrxns cusBtId: 232057823
I20170509-15:22:09.095(0)?      Exception while invoking method 'findCustTrxns' TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
I20170509-15:22:09.095(0)?      End Stream cnt: 56
```

> 

Comment: Which version of Meteor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to make it work:
1. Added a callback function 
  function getTrxns(cid,**callback** )
2. invoked the callback in stream.on('end;..) Here is the code

```
         function getTrxns(cid,callback ) {

      var trxns = [];
      var i = 0
      var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
                            r =     search.customerId().is(cid)});

      stream.on("data", function(data){
            i = i+1
            trxns.push({
               'id':data.id,
            });
     });
    stream.on("end", function(){
        // print the output in console
        console.log('End Stream cnt: '+i);
        callback('', trxns);
    });

    stream.resume();
    }



3. Changed the Meteor Method :

 findCustTrxns: function(btId) {


        if (!btId) { return []; };
        console.log('findCustTrxns cusBtId: '+btId);

 var trxns = [];
  var i = 0;

        var fn = Meteor.wrapAsync(getTrxns);  //made it a synchronous call
        try {
           var res = fn(btId);
           if (res) {
                console.log('Got data from getTrxns ');
                return res;
           }
        } catch( err) {
                console.log('Error calling hetTrxns '+err);
        }
 }, //findCustTrxns
```

Now I am able to get the Transactions. Hope it helps